# How to evaluate the following integral in Chapter 2 of Griffiths' Introduction to Electrodynamics?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

How to evaluate the following integral?

$$ \int_{0}^{L}\frac{1}{(x^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\mathrm{d}x $$

I tried to use following methods of substitution to evaluate it, but failed.

(1) Let $u= x^2+z^2$.

(2) Let $ x=z\tan t$.

Could you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Go on with the second substitution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{align}
\int_0^L\frac{1}{(x^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dx&=\int_0^{\arctan(\frac{L}{z})}\frac{1}{(z^2\tan^2t+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}z\sec^2tdt\hspace{1cm}\text{(By $x=z\tan t$)}\\
&=\int_0^{\arctan(\frac{L}{z})}\frac{z\sec^2t}{(z^2(\tan^2t+1))^{\frac{3}{2}}}dt\\
&=\int_0^{\arctan(\frac{L}{z})}\frac{z\sec^2t}{(z^2\sec^2t)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dt\\
&=\int_0^{\arctan(\frac{L}{z})}\frac{z\sec^2t}{z^3\sec^3t}dt\\
&=z^{-2}\int_0^{\arctan(\frac{L}{z})} \cos t \; dt\\
&=z^{-2} \sin t|_{t=0}^{t=\arctan(\frac{L}{z})}\\
&=z^{-2} \sin(\arctan(\frac{L}{z}))\\
&=z^{-2}\frac{L}{\sqrt{L^2+z^2}}\\
&=\frac{L}{z^2\sqrt{L^2+z^2}}\\
\end{align}$

Comment: L=3 z=5 https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral_0%5E3+1%2F%28x%5E2%2B25%29%5E%283%2F2%29

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's great!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $y=\frac{z^2}{x^2}$

$$ \int_{0}^{L}\frac{1}{(x^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{d}x 
= \int_{0}^{L}\frac{1}{x^3(1+\frac{z^2}{x^2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}{d}x 
=\int^\infty_{\frac{z^2}{L^2}}\frac{ \frac1{2z^2}}{(1+y)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{d}y$$